# Despliegue en Azure - No se cargan todos los archivos

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

Realize un despliegue en azure, sin embargo al ingresar a la aplicacion me lanza el siguiente error al ir a cada uno de los menus de la web.

[image: Error]

Al revisar encontre que no todos los archivos fueron cargados, ya que hacen falta algunas carpetas como Models y Controllers

[image: Archivos servidor]

Sin embargo dichas carpetas si las tengo en el proyecto local

[image: Carpetas local]

Ya realize de nuevo el despliegue pero aun no se cargan los archivos faltantes

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un despliegue se suben los archivos compilados, los .cs no deben subirse, lo primero es validar los connectionstring que esten apuntando a las bases de datos de azure, si esta correcto debes buscar los logs de error para ver el detalle de por que te esta fallando la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente habia un problema con los connectionstring. El proyecto ya funciona correctamente